# Does a path exists from root to leaf in a Binary Tree

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

I've written a small code which when given a binary tree, a number, when we add up the nodes values from root to leaf, if it equals to the number, returns true, else returns false.

```
boolean pathExists(BinaryTreeNode<Integer> root,int sum,int value) {
    if(root==null)
        return false;
    sum=sum+root.data;
    if(sum==value && root.left==null && root.right==null) {
        return true;
    }
    boolean found=pathExists(root.left, sum,value);
    if(found)
        return true;
    boolean check=pathExists(root.right, sum, value);
    if(check)
        return true;
    sum=sum-root.data;
    return false;
}
```

I think it works for all test cases, but if it doesn't work for any test case, please let me know. My major doubt is there any better version to write the code with the logic I've done, like making the code look better? Like instead of making the 2 variables found,check and then returning true by putting them in if statements, is it possible to put them into one single line like we generally see in recursive problems? Something like this-

`return pathExists(root.left, sum,value) || pathExists(root.right, sum,value);`

Clearly, the above statement wouldn't work but is there any such approach? I'm sorry to ask such a basic question, but I've always had pretty hard time with recursion, and it increased a lot in trees.

Comment: It is not the right site for this. If you have no problem with your actual code, we cannot help you. If I can give you an advise, write unit tests for each possible use case of your method. It should answer to your question.

Comment: @davidxxx Bro, stackoverflow isn't the right site for suggesting a better alternative to the code I've written? Is that the actual meaning...?

Comment: That's correct - the Code Review site is where you can ask for feedback on working code.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend writing a unit test that procedurally generates a few sets of 
1) All true responses (to ensure no false negatives)
2) All false responses (to ensure no false positives)
3) Any fringe cases that you may have encountered while writing the function (though given its simplicity, it may not really have any.)